# MS Access 2010 Subform ODBC Connection failed error

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010, subform

I have an Access database with linked tables to a SQL Server 2012 database.  It contains a Form/Subform for adding and editing data.  In the subform is a Combo Box with a LostFocus event that pulls data from a third table (default billing amount for the selected billing code).  If I have only the subform open in Form View, this lookup works perfectly.  However, if I try to do exactly the same action with the main form open, I get the error "ODBC--connection to 'Datasource' failed."

There is nothing wrong with the datasource.  I can pull up all the tables, and as I said this same action works correctly if only the subform is open.  There's something about having the main form open that seems to cause the problem.  I have searched both Stack Overflow and Google and haven't seen anything about this specific problem.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I wonder if the main form property "Record Locks" might effect this. If it is set to "All records" AND the combo box has it's property "allow value list edits" set to true..... just a  thought.

Comment: Can you post some information about your datasource connection string?  I'm wondering if you're using some kind of connection pool with a limit of 1 connection or something like that.  i.e. is the main form using up all of your available connections?  (Is the database is single-user mode?)  I'd head down that kind of path.

Comment: @DeadZone.  That has got to be it...

Comment: Thanks for your responses!  @DeadZone, I am just using ODBC to connect to SQL Server.  Happy to change that if there's something more reliable.

Comment: @HarveyFrench, Record Locks = "No Locks", Cycle = "All Records" (if that even matters), and the combo box's Allow Value List Edits was set to "Yes".  I changed that to "No", just for grins, but no change.